# How to customize a tikzcd figure

Tags: line-breaking, tikz-cd

I generated the following tikzcd diagram:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
                       &                            &  & {} \arrow[d] \arrow[llld] \arrow[rrrd] &                                                              &                                 &                        &                                &                      \\
\text{A} \arrow[d] \arrow[rd] &                            &  & \text{E} \arrow[d] \arrow[rd]                 &                                                              &                                 & \text{I} \arrow[d] \arrow[rd] &                                &                      \\
\text{a} \arrow[d]            & \emptyset  \arrow[d]       &  & \textlengthmark \arrow[d]              & \emptyset \arrow[d] \arrow[d] \arrow[d] \arrow[d] \arrow[rd] &                                 & \text{i\textesh} \arrow[d]    & \emptyset \arrow[d] \arrow[rd] &                      \\
a-\text{verbs}                & \text{suppletion} \arrow[d]       &  & \text{long}~e\text{-verbs}                           & e\text{-verbs}                                                      & \text{suppletion} \arrow[ld] \arrow[d] & i{\textesh}\text{-verbs}      & i\text{-verbs}                        & \text{suppletion} \arrow[d] \\
                       & \text{missing~ suffixes} \arrow[d] &  &                                        & L-pattern                                                    & \text{missing ~suffixes} \arrow[d]      &                        &                                & L-pattern            \\
                       & l\hat{a}\text{-like verbs}          &  &                                        &                                                              & sav\hat{e}\text{-like~verbs}                 &                        &                                &                     
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I want to add two words - T-pattern and muri- below the L-pattern (the one in the leftmost part of the diagram). However I do not manage to split the cell into three by simply using \.
I want to do the same below save-like verbs. There I want to add the words "vole" and "essi"
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `forest` may be a better tool here than `tikz-cd`.

Here is a start. You can make many many adjustments using tools from the `forest` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest, tipa}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={edge={->}, parent anchor=children, align=center}
[
    [A
        [a[a-verbs]]
        [$\emptyset$[suppletion[missing suffixes[l\^{a}-like verbs]]]]
    ]
    [E
        [:[long e-verbs]]
        [$\emptyset$
            [e-verbs]
            [suppletion[L-pattern\\T-pattern\\muri][missing suffixes[sav\^{e}-like verbs\\vole\\essi]]]
        ]
    ]
    [I
        [i\textesh[iS-verbs]]
        [$\emptyset$[i-verbs][suppletion[L-pattern]]]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```